# writing a class in python with main

Tags: python

I have written the following code based on a skeleton for a class i am in, it is based around the concept of classes. I have written the class and written the main but i continually get the same error that the functions within the class are undefined here is my code:

```
class Person:
    population = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print ('Initializing' ,self.name)
        Person.population += 1
    def __del__(self):
        print (self.name,"says bye.")
        Person.population -= 1
        if Person.population == 0:
            print ('I was the last one.')
        else:
            print ('There is/are still',Person.population ,'person/persons left.')  
    def sayHi(self):
        print("Hi, my name is ",self.name)
    def howMany(self):
        #Prints the current population.
        print(Person.population)
        #If there is only 1 person then it should print "I am the only one"
        if Person.population == 1:
            print("I am the only one")
            #If there are 2 people for example , then print "We have 2 people here"
        if Person.population == 2:
            print("We have 2 people here")
def main():

  # Step 1: Ask for names of 2 people
  x=input("name of person one?")
  y=input("name of person two?") 
  # Step 2: Initialize Person 1
  init1=__init__(x)
  # Step 3: Use function sayHi() for Person 1
  init1.sayHi()
  # Step 4: Use howMany() for Person 1
  init1.howMany()
  # Step 5: Initialize Person 2
  init2=__init__(y)
  # Step 6: Use function sayHi() for Person 2
  init2.sayHi()
  # Step 7: Use howMany() for Person 2
  init2.howMany()
  # Step 8: Say Hi to Person 1
  # Step 9: Use howMany() for Person 1
  init1.howMany()
  # Step 10: Terminate Person 1
  init1.__del__()
  # Step 11: Terminate Person 2
  init2.__del__()

main()
```

it continually produces the error `NameError: name __init__ is not defined` can anyone give me any insight into why this is occuring?

Comment: Check your indentation. The methods of a class must be indented in from the class declaration.

Comment: @PaulRooney: That can't be the original code, you'd get `IndentationError` for an empty `class`.

Comment: sorry the indentation is proper, it just did not transfer right.

Comment: Basically, you should never directly call any `__xxxx__` methods; they are magic, and meant for use by Python. `__init__` is called by the constructor, and `__del__` when the object is about to go away.

Comment: You never created the objects. You might want to look at some basic instructional materials on OOP in Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Person:
 population = 0
 def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    print ('Initializing' ,self.name)
    Person.population += 1
 def __del__(self):
    print (self.name,"says bye.")
    Person.population -= 1
    if Person.population == 0:
        print ('I was the last one.')
    else:
        print ('There is/are still',Person.population ,'person/persons left.')  
 def sayHi(self):
    print("Hi, my name is ",self.name)
 def howMany(self):
    #Prints the current population.
    print(Person.population)
    #If there is only 1 person then it should print "I am the only one"
    if Person.population == 1:
        print("I am the only one")
            #If there are 2 people for example , then print "We have 2 people here"
    if Person.population == 2:
        print("We have 2 people here")
def main():

  # Step 1: Ask for names of 2 people
  x=input("name of person one?")
  y=input("name of person two?") 
  # Step 2: Initialize Person 1
  init1= Person(x)
  # Step 3: Use function sayHi() for Person 1
  init1.sayHi()
  # Step 4: Use howMany() for Person 1
  init1.howMany()
  # Step 5: Initialize Person 2
  init2= Person(y)
  # Step 6: Use function sayHi() for Person 2
  init2.sayHi()
  # Step 7: Use howMany() for Person 2
  init2.howMany()
  # Step 8: Say Hi to Person 1
  # Step 9: Use howMany() for Person 1
  init1.howMany()
  init1 = None
  init2 = None

main()
```

Comment: this helped me thank you! once i figured out how to call it right it was simple thanks

Comment: Then mark the answer as correct answer, so that other can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` is defined inside your class. Thus there is no such function `__init__` you can call outside your class, which you do in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `__init__` as a global function. It is a method of `Person`. Despite this fact you do not need to call `__init__` yourself explicitly.

You can just call.

```
init1 = Person(x)
```

Also you do not need to call `__del__` explicitly either. It will be called automatically when the object is garbage collected (at the end of the script). So you can simply remove your calls to `__del__`